# Symfony3 Doctrine Hautelook/Alice cannot load fixtures

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony, alice-fixtures

Im using Symfony3 in my Project along with Doctrine ORM.
Now i wanted to have some nice fixtures with Hautelook/AliceBundle.

So i was installing the bundle, registering it to the AppKernel as well as making an entry in the config.

I added a DataLoader like this:

```
use Hautelook\AliceBundle\Doctrine\DataFixtures\AbstractLoader;

class DataLoader extends AbstractLoader
{
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getFixtures()
{
    return [
        __DIR__.'/../ORM/user.yml',
    ];
}
}
```

Now if i try to run the command like:

```
 sf hautelook_alice:doctrine:fixtures:load
```

I get the ErrorMessage:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedMethodException]                                                    
Attempted to call an undefined method named "addClass" of class "Doctrine\ORM\Internal\CommitOrderCalculator".
```

My composer.json contains of:

```
"doctrine/orm"                                          : "^2.5.4",
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle"                              : "^1.6",
"doctrine/data-fixtures"                                : "^1.1",
"hautelook/alice-bundle"                                : "^1.2",
"doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle"                     : "^2.3",
```

I really dont know what the issue here is, i hope anyone can help me to find out or knows the solution.
If any information is missing, i will add it afap.

Thx in advance

Comment: Where have you used "CommitOrderCalculator"? Can you show that code? That's what the error is saying; and you are calling "addClass".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve this issue with the following changes to my composer.json:

```
"doctrine/data-fixtures": "dev-topological-sorter as 1.1.x-dev"
```

The issue is already linked on github, but it was not merged into yet.
You can read more about it here:

https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures/pull/222/commits/987e5f35142ac4ac5dc60a16d1eb18293964bc25

I hope this will help other ppl having the same issue.

And thx to Alvin for trying to help me out.